# performance issue with TCP client and server program using android and PC

Tags: java, android, tcp, android-emulator, socket.io

I have written a java TCP server program. And I am going to run that program on my PC. I have written a java TCP client program which I will run on android emulator. I will connect to server using ip address 10.0.2.2 since I am using android emulator. But the performance is very poor. The server is receiving the data sent by client after nearly 8-10 minutes. And the emulator is not receiving any data from server. Please see where it is going wrong?

TCP SERVER(RUNS IN PC):

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

class TCPServer
{
   public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception
      {
         String clientSentence;
         String capitalizedSentence=null;
         ServerSocket welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(9000);

         while(true)
         {
            Socket connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();
            BufferedReader inFromClient =new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connectionSocket.getInputStream()));
            DataOutputStream outToClient = new DataOutputStream(connectionSocket.getOutputStream());
            clientSentence = inFromClient.readLine();
            System.out.println("Received: " + clientSentence);
            if(clientSentence.equals("IS COMPUTER ON?"))
            {
                capitalizedSentence = "YES SYSTEM IS ON.";
            }
            outToClient.writeBytes(capitalizedSentence);
         }
      }
}
```

TCP CLIENT(RUNS IN ANDROID EMULATOR):

```
package a.b.c;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.Socket;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class WifitestActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        try
        {
            String sentence="IS COMPUTER ON?";
            String modifiedSentence=sentence;
            Socket clientSocket = new Socket("10.0.2.2", 9000);
            DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
            BufferedReader inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
            outToServer.writeBytes(sentence);
            modifiedSentence = inFromServer.readLine();
            TextView a=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            a.setText(modifiedSentence);
            a.showContextMenu();
            clientSocket.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            TextView a=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            a.setText(e.toString());
            a.showContextMenu();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the [network delay option](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/emulator.html#netdelay) for your emulator ?
Also can you please see that not many processes are running on the machine as those processes may steal the CPU cycles you expect your emulator to consume

Answer (score 0):

Few tips

1. For creating a Client Socket use the following

   The constructor `Socket(String host, int port)` can block indefinitely until an initial  connection to the host is established.

You can overcome this problem by first constructing an unconnected socket and then connecting it with a timeout:

```
Socket s = new Socket();
s.connect(new InetSocketAddress(host, port), timeout);
```

1. On the Server side use Only `PrintWriter`, as it will work as bridge itself between the low level byte from socket and character data.

   eg:
          Code for the Server

   ```
   public class ServerTest {

   ServerSocket s;

   public void go() {

       try {
           s = new ServerSocket(44457);

           while (true) {

               Socket incoming = s.accept();
               Thread t = new Thread(new MyCon(incoming));
               t.start();
           }
       } catch (IOException e) {

           e.printStackTrace();
       }

   }

   class MyCon implements Runnable {

       Socket incoming;

       public MyCon(Socket incoming) {

           this.incoming = incoming;
       }

       @Override
       public void run() {

           try {
               PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(incoming.getOutputStream(),
                       true);
               InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(
                       incoming.getInputStream());
               BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
               String inp = null;

               boolean isDone = true;

               System.out.println("TYPE : BYE");
               System.out.println();
               while (isDone && ((inp = br.readLine()) != null)) {

                   System.out.println(inp);
                   if (inp.trim().equals("BYE")) {
                       System.out
                               .println("THANKS FOR CONNECTING...Bye for now");
                       isDone = false;
                       s.close();
                   }

               }
           } catch (IOException e) {
               // TODO Auto-generated catch block
               try {
                   s.close();
               } catch (IOException e1) {
                   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                   e1.printStackTrace();
               }
               e.printStackTrace();
           }

       }

   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {

       new ServerTest().go();

   }
   ```

   }